# how to get the value of a textarea in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

i have this form and im trying to get the value from the text area. for some reason it doesn't want to.

```
<form action="/profile/index/sendmessage" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div class="upload_form">
        <dt id="message-label"><label class="optional" for="message">Enter Message</label></dt>
        <dd id="message-element">
        <textarea cols="60" rows="5" id="message" name="message"></textarea></dd>
        <dt id="id-label">&nbsp;</dt>
        <dd id="id-element">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" value="145198" name="id"></dd>
        <dt id="send_message-label">&nbsp;</dt>
        <dd id="send_message-element">
        <input type="submit" class="sendamessage" value="Send" id="send_message" name="send_message"></dd>
    </div>
</form>


$("input.sendamessage").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var message = $('textarea#message').html();
    var id      = $('input#id').val();

    console.log(message + '-' + id);
});
```

or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/SvbZJ/1/)

any ideas?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Value of textarea is also taken with [`val`](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val1) method:

```js
var message = $('textarea#message').val();
console.log(message);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="60" rows="5" id="message" name="message">
Hello,
 world!
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 29):

You need to use `.val()` for textarea as it is an element and not a wrapper. Try

```
$('textarea#message').val()
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/SvbZJ/2/)

Answer (score 23):

you should use `val()` instead of `html()`

```
var message = $('#message').val();
```

Answer (score 22):

in javascript :

```
document.getElementById("message").value
```

Comment: From [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea): "`<textarea>` does not support the `value` attribute."

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: nobody is talking about the attribute of the `textarea` element, it's about retrieving the contents of the element.

Comment: @Forage then what does `.value` mean?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: Like I said, and Saurabh for that matter, it will get you the contents of the `textarea` element, the text someone typed into the field. If an element (like `input`) has a `value` attribute you can retrieve it with `document.getElementById("message").getAttribute("value")`.

Comment: @Forage just because it works in same cases, doesn't make it right. Or maybe you should report an issue with Mozilla's documentation.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: you are mixing things up. The Mozilla docs state correctly that the `value` attribute on `textarea` element is not supported, so you can't do `<textarea value="..."></textarea>` . This attribute is e.g. for the `input` element to give it a pre-filled value. `.value` in JS is something else, it's not to retrieve the value of the `value` attribute but the contents, so what's between `<textarea>...</textarea>`. Thus exactly what the OP is asking, but without the need for jQuery.

Comment: @Forage there's the HTML syntax which doesn't have the `value` attribute and there's also the JavaScript API which has a `value` attribute. They don't have to be identical. New HTML standards could have some attributes which aren't supported by old JS engines, say `blink`, and JS engines could for example have computed attributes, say `number_of_words` which make no sense for the HTML source code. Is this what you're trying to say?

Comment: All I'm saying is that the spec you are referring to is for HTML, not JS/DOM. And yes, a HTML _attribute_ is not the same as a JS/DOM _property_. We are talking about an element's JS/DOM `value` _property_ here, which is perfectly valid according to the spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement. So you initial comment is true, the `textarea` HTML element does not have a `value` HTML _attribute_, but that does not make Saurabh's answer wrong, because it's a different subject.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use `textarea#message`

```
var message = $('textarea#message').val();
```

You can directly use

```
var message = $('#message').val();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should check the textarea is null before you use val() otherwise, you will get undefined error.

```
if ($('textarea#message') != undefined) {
   var message = $('textarea#message').val();
}
```

Then, you could do whatever with message.

Comment: This is incorrect. jQuery never returns undefined for any query. Instead, it returns an empty set. However, calling val on an empty set returns an undefined, but your answer does not solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use

```
var message = $.trim($("#message").val());
```

Read more @ [Get the Value of TextArea using the jQuery Val () Method](http://www.jquerypot.com/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-textarea-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 3):

You can also get the value by element's **name attribute**.

```
var message = $("#formId textarea[name=message]").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('textarea#message')` cannot be undefined (if by `$` you mean jQuery of course).

`$('textarea#message')` may be of length 0 and then `$('textarea#message').val()` would be empty that's all

Answer (score 2):

all Values is always taken with `.val()`.

see the code bellow:

```
var message = $('#message').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `.html()`. You should go with `.val()`.

From the doc of [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/):

> The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`. When called on an empty collection, it returns `undefined`.

```
var message = $('#message').val();
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also get value by name instead of id like this:

```
var message = $('textarea:input[name=message]').val();
```