# populating a div with html with query

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get the value of a textarea in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507294/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-textarea-in-jquery)

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="textdescription"></div>
```

And the following jQuery (var gets value from a form textarea):

```
var description = $('#inputDescription').html();
$('#textdescription').html(description);
```

How can I get the value into #description

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) : val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/): Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements.

[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/): Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.

```
   var description = $('#inputDescription').val();
     $('#textdescription').html(description);
```

see demo here [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tAXYg/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#description").val("something you want to put");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
$('#inputDescription').val();
```

for input(including textarea) elements instead of `.html()`

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/Gbt9L/)