# Trying to submit a form using onclick event, also append values in formData

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to submit a form using `onclick` event since I need to pass a value to that function as well. But when I click the `submit` button, the page reloads and shows no data. Also, the textarea is empty and is not picking up the values.

**Let me show you the code:**

```
<form action="" id="form_content">
    <textarea name="textdata" id="content" cols="50" rows="50" class="form-control message" placeholder="Whats on your mind ?"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" onclick="comment_here('+post_id+');">Comment</button></form>
```

**The script:**

```
function comment_here($post_id) {
    // alert($post_id);
    document.getElementById("form_content").submit();

    var Post_id=$post_id;
    var User_id = $('.id_data').attr('value');
    var textdata = $("#content").val();
    alert(textdata);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'<?php echo base_url("user/post_comment"); ?>',
        data: {Post_id:Post_id,User_id:User_id,textdata:textdata},
        dataType: 'json', 
        success:function(data) {
            alert('you have like this');
        }
    });

});
}
```

This is my code, but its now working. Can you tell me where I am wrong?

**edited attempt:**

```
jQuery('#comment_button').on('onclick',function(e){
    alert('data');
    var Post_id=$post_id;
    var User_id = $('.id_data').attr('value');
    var textdata = $("#content").val();
    alert(textdata);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'<?php echo base_url("user/post_comment"); ?>',
        data: {Post_id:Post_id,User_id:User_id,textdata:textdata},
        dataType: 'json', 
        success:function(data) {
            alert('you have like this');
        }
    });    
});
```

edited

```
$(document).on('click','#comment_button',function(e){
    // this will prevent form and reload page on submit.
    e.preventDefault();
    var Post_id=$post_id;
    var User_id = $('.id_data').attr('value');
    // here you will get Post ID

     var textdata = $('textarea#content').val();
    alert(textdata);
   // Add your Ajax call here.
   $.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                  url:'<?php echo base_url("user/post_comment"); ?>',
                  data: {textdata:textdata},
                  dataType: 'json', 
                  success:function(data)
                  {
                    alert('you have like this');
                  }
```

Comment: you are going on old way of javascript.

Comment: what else can i do ? @TejasMehta

Comment: Use jQuery "on " selector with button and onClick you can pass function(e) and e,preventDefault(); will not allow you to submit form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7056673/6369494 check this answer

Comment: sorry it semms to be not working i added jQuery('#comment_button').on('onclick',function(e){
e.preventDefault(); and gave the id "comment_button" but it still not working @TejasMehta

Comment: Post your form, let's see what that looks like. Also, add your edited attempt, it would help to see it all.

Comment: Please post your full code

Comment: form's already posted @TejasMehta

Comment: what else should i post? @TejasMehta

Comment: It's `jQuery('#comment_button').on('click',function(e){` not `jQuery('#comment_button').on('onclick',function(e){`. `click` vs `onclick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added Data attribute of the HTML5 and try this code it is working perfectly as you want,

You can add form.serialize() also in the data of the ajax,

```js
$(document).on('click','#button_comment',function(e){
    // this will prevent form and reload page on submit.
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // here you will get Post ID
    my_post_id=$(this).attr('data-postId');
    var User_id = $('.id_data').attr('value');
    var textdata = $('textarea#content').val();
    alert(textdata);

   // Add your Ajax call here.
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="form_content">

<textarea name="textdata" id="content" cols="25" rows="10"  class="form-control message"  placeholder="Whats on your mind ?"></textarea>

<!-- use Data attribute that save post id on submit button -->

<button type="submit" id="button_comment" data-postId="12">Comment</button></form>
```

Comment: thanks @TejasMehta i got the 'click' function but the textdata value is not passing it is empty.

Comment: you can get by this $('textarea#content').val() @HimanshuGoyal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507294/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-textarea-in-jquery check this link for textarea value

Comment: this is what i am using now but the textdata when alerting is empty

Comment: Remove the space in/between your textarea html tag , sometimes it also cause this type of issue, also try with jQuery instead of $

Comment: Run my code above Bro, I am getting values of textarea, see i have alerted it,

Comment: in your snippet i can run this and get the value of textarea but when i try that code it still shows empty. can you check my edited code above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137405/discussion-between-tejas-mehta-and-himanshu-goyal).

Comment: there was error beacuse var textdata = $('textarea#content').val(); it showing empty but when i changed it to var textdata = $('#content').val(); it works

Answer (score 1):

**You can follow this instruction from this site as
it will be useful for you i think** 
https://www.formget.com/javascript-submit-form/

```js
// Submit form with id function.
function submit_by_id() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
if (validation()) // Calling validation function
{
document.getElementById("form_id").submit(); //form submission
alert(" Name : " + name + " \n Email : " + email + " \n Form Id : " + document.getElementById("form_id").getAttribute("id") + "\n\n Form Submitted Successfully......");
}
}

// Submit form with name function.
function submit_by_name() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
if (validation()) // Calling validation function
{
var x = document.getElementsByName('form_name');
x[0].submit(); //form submission
alert(" Name : " + name + " \n Email : " + email + " \n Form Name : " + document.getElementById("form_id").getAttribute("name") + "\n\n Form Submitted Successfully......");
}
}

// Submit form with class function.
function submit_by_class() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
if (validation()) // Calling validation function
{
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("form_class");
x[0].submit(); //form submission
alert(" Name : " + name + " \n Email : " + email + " \n Form Class : " + document.getElementById("form_id").getAttribute("class") + "\n\n Form Submitted Successfully......");
}
}

// Submit form with HTML <form> tag function.
function submit_by_tag() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
if (validation()) // Calling validation function
{
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
x[0].submit(); //form submission
alert(" Name : " + name + " \n Email : " + email + " \n Form Tag : <form>\n\n Form Submitted Successfully......");
}
}

// Name and Email validation Function.
function validation() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
if (name === '' || email === '') {
alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
return false;
} else if (!(email).match(emailReg)) {
alert("Invalid Email...!!!!!!");
return false;
} else {
return true;
}
}
```

```css
/* Below line is used for online Google font */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
h2{
background-color: #FEFFED;
padding: 30px 35px;
margin: -10px -50px;
text-align:center;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
hr{
margin: 10px -50px;
border: 0;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
margin-bottom: 40px;
}
div.container{
width: 900px;
height: 610px;
margin:35px auto;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
div.main{
width: 300px;
padding: 10px 50px 10px;
border: 2px solid gray;
border-radius: 10px;
font-family: raleway;
float:left;
margin-top:60px;
}
input[type=text]{
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
padding: 5px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
margin-top: 5px;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
color: #4f4f4f;
font-size: 16px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
label{
color: #464646;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
}
#btn_id,#btn_name,#btn_class,#btn_tag{
font-size: 16px;
background: linear-gradient(#ffbc00 5%, #ffdd7f 100%);
border: 1px solid #e5a900;
color: #4E4D4B;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
width: 47.5%;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-bottom:10px;
padding: 7px 0;
}
#btn_id:hover,#btn_name:hover,#btn_class:hover,#btn_tag:hover{
background: linear-gradient(#ffdd7f 5%, #ffbc00 100%);
}
#btn_name,#btn_tag{
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Form Submit Example</title>
<!-- Include CSS File Here -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/submit_javascript.css"/>
<!-- Include JS File Here -->
<script src="js/submit_javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="main">
<form action="#" method="post" name="form_name" id="form_id" class="form_class" >
<h2>Javascript Form Submit</h2>
<label>Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
<label>Email :</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Valid Email" />
<input type="button" name="submit_id" id="btn_id" value="Submit by Id" onclick="submit_by_id()"/>
<input type="button" name="submit_name" id="btn_name" value="Submit by Name" onclick="submit_by_name()"/>
<input type="button" name="submit_class" id="btn_class" value="Submit by Class" onclick="submit_by_class()"/>
<input type="button" name="submit_tag" id="btn_tag" value="Submit by Tag" onclick="submit_by_tag()"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i already tried that method but i cant pick the values from this using the name @BKarthikKumar

Comment: // Name and Email validation Function.
function validation(){
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var emailReg = /^([w-.]+@([w-]+.)+[w-]{2,4})?$/;
if( name ==='' || email ===''){
alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
return false;
}else if(!(email).match(emailReg)){
alert("Invalid Email...!!!!!!");
return false;
}else{
return true;
}
}
@HimanshuGoyal
jus use this with above code you can pick the values from this using the name

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `onclick` with wrong parameter, `onclick` must be like:

```
onclick="delete_row('<?php echo $row['sid'];?>');"
```

Then, your jQuery `function comment_here($post_id)` is also wrong. You can't define variable as php using `$`. use `function comment_here(post_id)` instead.
after this try to get value and print it first and use according to your needs.

Comment: onclick=function('.php tags and its variable you want to pass.')