# Cannot regex a textarea, but can if its an input

Tags: php, regex, input, textarea, jscript

I have a box for user input, but I need it to be an input area that can be used like a notepad and not just one line.

I made a text area but when I try to regex the value, it does not handle it and ignores the regex.. but an input handles the regex..

Why is this and how can I regex a text area's input?

```
<div class='container' >

<div class='listtitle' title='Describe Your Items & Give Your Listing as Much Detail As You Can' >Info<br>
<h5>Give Your Listing as Much Detail As You Can.</h5>
</div>
```

```
<div id ='infofooter' class='listfooter'>Max Letters: 250</div>

</div><!--container2--->    


<script>


$(document).ready(function () {

      $('#infovalue').keyup(checkinfo);

});

function checkinfo() {


var info = $("#infovalue").val();
var infoReg = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-+&%#=?<>()£~_\.*!, ]{3,54}$/;


    if(!infoReg.test(info)) { 
        $("#infofooter").text("0-250 Standard Characters Please!"), $( "#infovalue" ).addClass( "errorclass" ), $( "#infovalue" ).removeClass( "noerrorclass");
                    }  

    if(infoReg.test(info)) { 
        $("#infofooter").text("info Is Good, Thanks!"), $( "#infovalue" ).addClass( "noerrorclass" ), $( "#infovalue" ).removeClass( "errorclass");
                    } 

var infoB = document.getElementById('infovalue');

var regex= lots/ of/ bad/ words/ - /edited /for /obvious /reasons/gi;
infoB.text=infoB.text.replace(regex, "****");   

};
```

//changed .text to .val .value also to no avail.

```
</script>
```

Comment: your using textarea wrong `<textarea class='textbox' name='info' id='infovalue'  cols="50" rows="10" required >
<?php echo $sellinginfo; ?>
</textarea>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: iv tried it everyway else, iv just got to the point of frustration now,, i  cant regex the textare because textarea dont use a value, so then how do i regex it, iv tried $('#infovalue').text & .value , also the $sellinginfo in the text area nit as a value and the rest, but i cant regex it for what reason i dont know

Comment: That last regex with lots of bad words is just something you put there to simplify the code right. Because that's not a regex. If you'd want to match forward slashes you'd have to escape them. F.e.  `re = /bla\/bla/g`

Comment: yes...iv got it the right way in editor

Comment: If the problem is in the regex, this can help you test it: https://regex101.com/

Comment: According to here `.val()` still works for textarea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507294/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-textarea-in-jquery You just need to make sure that your placing the value correctly the comment by smith is correct on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems with your code. Like missing opening/closing quotes, etc.
In respect to your attempt to filter/replace "bad words", this is simply no regex syntax.

Try it like that:

```
regex= /\b(?:lots|bad|words|edited|for|obvious|reasons)\b/gi;
```

If you do not want substring matches, remove the `\b` word boundaries from the pattern.

I have also added `/r/n` to the first regex in the sample below, if this is the issue:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#infovalue').keyup(checkinfo);
});

function checkinfo() {

var info = $("#infovalue").val();
var infoReg = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-+&%#=?<>\(\)£~_\\.*!, \r\n]{3,54}$/;

    if(!infoReg.test(info)) { 
        $("#infofooter").text("0-250 Standard Characters Please!"), $( "#infovalue" ).addClass( "errorclass" ), $( "#infovalue" ).removeClass( "noerrorclass");
                    }  

    if(infoReg.test(info)) {
        $("#infofooter").text("info Is Good, Thanks!"), $( "#infovalue" ).addClass( "noerrorclass" ), $( "#infovalue" ).removeClass( "errorclass");
                    } 

var infoB = document.getElementById('infovalue');

var regex= /\b(?:lots|bad|words|edited|for|obvious|reasons)\b/gi;
infoB.value=infoB.value.replace(regex, "****"); 

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container' >

<div class='listtitle' title='Describe Your Items & Give Your Listing as Much Detail As You Can' >Info<br>
<h5>Give Your Listing as Much Detail As You Can.</h5>
</div>
<textarea class='textbox' name='info' id='infovalue' cols="50" rows="10" value="" required >
</input>
<div id ='infofooter' class='listfooter'>Max Letters: 250</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. iv narrowed the problem down to carriage returns... the variable for whatever reason was carriage returning and the regex dont have carriage returns so it threw the error every-time. so i think i have to add a /r or /r/n to the regex.

Comment: </textarea> instead of </input>

Comment: Thank you. Working now. it was the \r\n

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but you're trying to put something in the value attribute, which I think works for inputs, but not for textarea elements. So maybe this fixes it:

```
<textarea class='textbox' name='info' id='infovalue' cols="50" rows="10" required ><?php echo $sellinginfo; ?></textarea>
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6007262/9638388

Comment: same thing... so if the variable is not a value, how do i regex it

Comment: it just throw the errorclass, and not a noerror class

Comment: Where do i put the /r for my regex any1       infoReg = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-+&%#=?<>\(\)£~_\.*!, /r]{3,54}$/;   not working

Comment: do you mean \r instead of /r ?