# Get ID from Element/Tag

Tags: html, html-table, datatable, prop

here is one given example:

```
<textarea style="width:300px" id="xxx_001" name="xxx_001"></textarea>
```

I want to get the value of ID

> "xxx_001"

here is my code:

```
$('.buttonclick').on('click', function() {

    var textareaval = $('#textareavalue').val();

    $("tbody").find("tr").each(function() { //get all rows in table

        var ratingTdText = $(this).find('td.selected'); // where in one column is selected

        // this is what i get textarea tag/element see above
        console.log("ratingTdText html(): "+ratingTdText.html() );  

        // i want to get only xxx_001
        console.log("ratingTdText only id: "+ratingTdText.attr('id') ); // doesn't happen
        console.log("ratingTdText only id: "+ratingTdText.prop('id') ); // doesn't happen

        var only_id = ratingTdText.attr('id');

        $("#textareaset_"+only_id).text(textareaval);
        $('#checkboxset_' + only_id).prop('checked', true);
        $('#selectoptionset_'+only_id).val('1');
    });
});
```

Please, do you have solution?

Here is some output:

```
console.log("ratingTdText: "+ratingTdText );
```

> ratingTdText: [object Object]

```
console.log("ratingTdText html(): "+ratingTdText.html() );
```

> ratingTdText html(): textarea style="width:300px" id="xxx_001 name="xxx_001">

```
console.log("ratingTdText only id attr(): "+ratingTdText.attr('id') );
```

> ratingTdText only id attr(): undefined

```
        console.log("ratingTdText only id prop(): "+ratingTdText.prop('id') );
```

> ratingTdText only id prop():

Comment: Add whole code for better clarity

Comment: Hello, i tried this one whole function. Hope this will clarify!

Comment: try this inside function to get id from 
 text area        
console.log(ratingTdText.find('textarea').attr('id'));
// basically ur putting data to text area  not to selected td if i am correct

Comment: Hello Harsha, you re correct. the textarea is inside in tag td. this is right answer. thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the value of a textarea in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507294/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-textarea-in-jquery)

Comment: thx for reply david. i did see this, but didn't help! it is about getting value from textarea. mine is getting from td and agaein from textarea

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.buttonclick').on('click', function() {

var textareaval = $('#textareavalue').val();

$("tbody").find("tr").each(function() { //get all rows in table

    var ratingTdText = $(this).find('td.selected'); // where in one column is selected

    // this is what i get textarea tag/element see above
    console.log("ratingTdText html(): "+ratingTdText.html() );  

    // i want to get only xxx_001
    console.log("ratingTdText only id: "+ratingTdText.attr(this) ); // doesn't happen
    console.log("ratingTdText only id: "+ratingTdText.prop(this) ); // doesn't happen

    var only_id = ratingTdText.attr('id');

    $("#textareaset_"+only_id).text(textareaval);
    $('#checkboxset_' + only_id).prop('checked', true);
    $('#selectoptionset_'+only_id).val('1');
});
```

});

Instead od using id try to use this it might work

Comment: thx for reply. tried this: console.log("ratingTdText only id attr(): "+ratingTdText.attr(this) ); 
output: Illegal invocation

Comment: tried this: console.log("ratingTdText only id attr(): "+ratingTdText.attr($(this)) );
outtput: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '0' is not a valid attribute name.

Comment: $('textarea').attr('id') you can directly use this

Comment: joshi thx for reply, but if i use this, what about selected?? Cause i need only this with td selected to get id attribute from textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from Harsha:

```
console.log("ratingTdText only id attr(): "+ratingTdText.find('textarea').attr('id') );
console.log("ratingTdText only id prop(): "+ratingTdText.find('textarea').prop('id') );
```

work perfectly fine! Many thanks.